# How to download jar from artifact registry (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artifact, google-artifact-registry

I have a maven Artifact Registry and am able to add dependency in pom.xml and get the jar.

I have another usecase where I would like to only download the jar using CLI something which you can easily do with other external maven repos eg `curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/iceberg/iceberg-spark-runtime/0.7.0-incubating/iceberg-spark-runtime-0.7.0-incubating.jar --output temp.jar`

I don't see any instructions about how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I needed this too.
I have configured a service account following  [gcp guide](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication)

Then, I have executed the following command to get authbasic credz :

```
gcloud artifacts print-settings gradle \
    [--project=PROJECT] \
    [--repository=REPOSITORY] \
    [--location=LOCATION] \
    --json-key=KEY-FILE \
    [--version-policy=VERSION-POLICY] \
    [--allow-snapshot-overwrites]
```

In the output you have the artifactRegistryMavenSecret.

Finally you get your artifact with :

```
curl -L -u _json_key_base64:{{ artifactRegistryMavenSecret }} https://{{ region }}-maven.pkg.dev/{{ projectId }}/{{ repository }}/path/of/artifact/module/{{ version }}/app-{{ version }}.jar -o file.jar
```

Comment: I am not being able to download a file in a GitHub Actions Runner (no matter what OS I use) no errors shown but the output file is small (a few bytes) any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Additional to @Nicolas Roux's answer:

`artifactRegistryMavenSecret` is basically an encode64 of the Service Account json key.

So instead of runnig `gcloud artifacts print-settings gradle` and `curl -u _json_key_base64:{{ artifactRegistryMavenSecret }}`, another way is you can directly use the token from `gcloud auth print-access-token`, then apply this token to `cURL`.

For example:

```
1. gcloud auth activate-service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT@DOMAIN.COM \
        --key-file=/path/key.json --project=PROJECT_ID
2. curl --oauth2-bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
        -o app-{{ version }}.jar \
        -L https://{{ region }}-maven.pkg.dev/{{ projectId }}/{{ repository }}/path/of/artifact/module/{{ version }}/app-{{ version }}.jar
```

By that, if you're working with Google Auth Action (google-github-actions/auth@v0) in Github Actions Workflow, then you can easily run the `curl` command without needing to extract `artifactRegistryMavenSecret`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this feature as mentioned does not exist yet for Artifact Registry based on this open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203557347) (this feature request has currently no ETA). However, you can try to implement a Cloud build automation not to only save your built artifact in Artifact Registry, but also to store them in Google Cloud Storage or other Storage repositories; so you can easily access the JARs (since Cloud Storage supports direct downloading).

In order to do this, you would need to [integrate](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-cloud-build#maven) Cloud Build with Artifact Registry. The documentation page has instructions to use Maven projects with Cloud Build and Artifact Registry. In addition, you can configure Cloud Build to store built [artifacts in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/store-build-artifacts).

Both of these integrations are configured through a [Cloud Build configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema). In this file, the steps for building a project are defined, including integrations to other serverless services. This integration would involve defining a target Maven repository:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn
  args: ['deploy']
```

And a location to deploy the artifacts into Cloud Storage:

```
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: [STORAGE_LOCATION]
    paths: [[ARTIFACT_PATH],[ARTIFACT_PATH], ...]
```

Comment: Was this information useful for your issue? in case it can help other users wanting to implement the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

Here is what work for me:

```
    1. gcloud auth login
    2. curl -H "Authorization: Bearer \"$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)\"" \
       -o my_deployment.jar \
       -L https://us-maven.pkg.dev/gcp_project/my_artifactory/my_code_project/1.17.0/my_deployment_version.jar
```

The link to the jar can be found while pushing to the artifact registry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you provide your identity token as Bearer token in `Authorization` header for curl and that's all.

Created several functions to do it, you just provide your lib name like in POM file or just as a path, then you are good to go.

```bash
lib-to-path() {
    # $1: lib name, like com.example.group.artifact:lib:jar:12345678, or com/example/group/artifact/lib/12345678
    echo $1 | sed 's/pom://g' | sed 's/jar://g' | sed 's/:jar//g' | sed 's/[:]/\//g' | sed -E 's/(\w*)\.(\w*)/\1\/\2/g'
}


fetch-lib-iap() {
    if [ -z $1 ]; then 
        echo "Please provide lib name, like com.example.group.artifact:lib:jar:12345678"
        return 1
    fi
    lib_path="$(lib-to-path $1)"
    path="/home/${USER}/.m2/repository/$lib_path"
    echo "Saving to location: $path"
    version="$(basename $path)"
    parent_dir="$(echo $path | sed "s/$version//g")"
    lib="$(basename $parent_dir)"
    cd "$parent_dir"
    mkdir "$version"
    cd "$version"
    echo "Parent dir: $parent_dir, lib: $lib, version: $version"
    url="https://nexus.example.com/repository/$lib_path"
    download-lib-jar-pom $url jar $lib $version
    download-lib-jar-pom $url pom $lib $version
}

download-lib-jar-pom() {
    # $1: url w/o extension, $2: extension, $3: lib, $4: version
    filename="$3-$4.$2"
    touch "$filename"
    echo "Downloading: $1/$filename"
    # -O: download to a file as the remote filename
    curl -s -k -O "$1/$filename" --connect-timeout 10 -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gauth-impersonate-nexus-token 2>/dev/null)"
    if [[ "$2" == "pom" ]] && (head -2 "$filename" | grep "DOCTYPE html"); then
        echo "ERROR POM file $1! Only found 404 page!"
        rm "$filename"
        return 1
    fi
    if [ "$(size $filename)" == 0 ] ; then
        echo "ERROR! $filename not found, download size 0!"
        rm "$filename"
        return 1
    fi
    cd -
}

gauth-impersonate-nexus-token() {
    gcloud auth print-identity-token --impersonate-service-account="nexus-user@example.com" --audiences="some-aud" --include-email
}
```